# In this program to determine whether number is palindrome or not, I can't figure out what's going wrong? I think scanf isn't even taking value

Tags: c, fatal-error

I tried to detect whether a number is palindrome or not without using library functions and without array. i don't think the logic is the problem here. I introduced printf's as a checkpoint after scan and some of the loops but i think the code isn't even reading the input as it is unable to print the value of input

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
 {
     long a,b,x,i,j,d,y;
     long g=0;
     long n=0;
     long c=10;
  printf("Enter a number: "); 
  scanf("%li",&a);   \\takes input
  printf("%li",a);   \\prints the scanned input(Checkpoint)
  do{
     n++;
     b=a/10;
    }while(b!=0);  \\to determine the number of digits in input
    printf("%li",n);  \\(checkpoint)
  x=a;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
   y=c*10;
printf("%li",y);  \\(checkpoint)
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)  \\store the reverse value of input in g
  {
   d=x%c;
   y=y/10;
   g=g+(d*y);
   x=x/10;
  }
  if(g==a)  \\check if number is palindrome
  {
   printf("Palindrome");
  }
  else
  {
   printf("Not a palindrome");
  }
  return(0);
 }
```

Comment: Always check what `scanf` [***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Your "comment markers" are the wrong way around: it should be `//`, not `\\\`.

Comment: And please don't tag multiple different languages in your posts, use only the tag for the language you're actually programming in.

Comment: Since you don't print any newline, you're not flushing the output buffer, so you don't see the checkpoints, so you don't notice that your first loop never ends. (How could `b` become zero if it's always `a/10` and `a` doesn't change?)

Answer (score 1):

In the loop

```
do{
     n++;
     b=a/10;
    }while(b!=0);
```

you never modify the value of `a`, so the result of `a/10` and thus the value of `b` will *always* be the same. If `a` is equal to or larger than `10` then you will have an infinite loop here, as `b` will never be equal to zero.

Since the output before the loop isn't *flushed* (actually written to the terminal) then it can look like the `scanf` call will never return.